# Unable to connect to SQL Server via JDBC. No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, tomcat, jdbc

I simply want to use SQL Server database in my HTTP Servlet program but my program can't seem to connect to the database. It gives me the following error:

> No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Bookyard;integratedSecurity=true;

This is my connection method.

```
package practice.bookyard.server.util;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Database {

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB:1433;databaseName=Bookyard;integratedSecurity=true;";
        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return connection;
    }

}
```

I had the sever name as `localhost:1433` earlier but I changed it to the SQL Server instance name `(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB:1433` but it still seems to pick up the old name.

Also, I am not sure how to provide the right connection string when connecting to SQL Server localdb.

I am using Eclipse for Java EE, Mars 2, and I downloaded Microsoft JDBC drivers for SQL 6.0 from [this website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774).

I ran the installation, unzipped the contents of the resulting folder. Then, I added the **sqljdbc42.jar** file to the build path as I am targeting JDK 1.8.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Upon Scary Wombat's suggestion, I have also added the path to the **sqljdbc42.jar** file to my classpath.

[image]

However, I still get the same error.

I am pretty confident this is a reflection issue, in that the type loader isn't able to resolve the driver type from my connection string. Which means, the connection string syntax I am using is wrong.

I changed my connection string to read as follows:

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;
instance=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;
databaseName=Bookyard;integratedSecurity=true;";
```

However, I still not only get the same error but the exception message I receive still has my *old connection string*. So, clearly, there's also some caching going on, I just don't know where. Who is caching my connection string and how do I refresh / clear that cache?

Could you please tell me how to provide a SQL Server instance name if I am connecting to **localdb** and not on the main SQL Server instance?

Comment: Can you check in SQL Server Configuration Manager whether TCP/IP is enabled? If its not enabled, you need to enable it. You probably need to restart your system as well after doing this change if I remember correctly.

Comment: The jar has to be on your classpath as well as on you buildpath.  The buildpath is only for compiling

Comment: @ScaryWombat How do I put it in the classpath? I am total newbie? Is that an environment variable?

Comment: @AdityaGupta Yes, TCP is enabled and I've connected to my SQL instance a million times from .NET applications.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Is the CLASS_PATH different from JAVA_HOME? I've got the latter set. If it is different, what must I set it to? The documentation is so confusing.

Comment: Ok. I get how to set the class path and what it is for. I'll give that a try.

Comment: Yes, they are different, as the name indicates it is the path for your external jars

Comment: To make it clear, the JAR file with JDBC driver **must** be either in `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your application, or in Tomcat's `lib` folder. In your case, I would suggest `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: You need to add the jar file in the Tomcat/lib folder.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek I added the jar to the `WEB-INF\lib` folder but still no hope. I've made a few more changes so I don't know what caused the exception to change now but now I get a clearer exception message that the class loader failed. It says: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ScaryWombat and @JozefChocholacek had hinted, it turned out to be a class path issue. Apparently, you have to copy and paste just the **sqljdbc42.jar** file, and this file only directly into the `WEB-INF\lib` folder and not within any sub-folder.

I did that it still gave me that error.

That was because the `WEB-INF` folder structure, when I viewed it in the `Project Explorer`, still had the old folder structure. So, I right-clicked on the `WEB-INF` folder in the `Project Explorer` and selected the `Refresh` command.

I also updated my environmental variable `CLASSPATH` to point it to the `WEB-INF` folder and that error went away.

Answer (score -2):

you can do like below

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://YOUR PC NAME;instanceName=SQLEXPRESS;DatabaseName=dbname;integratedSecurity=true";

Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
Connection myCon = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

note :however its not necceaary for new version of jdbc driver to load driver class manually using class.forname